# If we know the column sum of a matrix, and the column sum of its row-normalized matrix, can we find the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm new to linear algebra and please forgive my unprofessional notation.

Let's say we have an unknown matrix $X$ of shape $M \times N$. We know

1. the sum of columns for $X$, and
2. the sum of columns for $X'$, which is a row-normalized matrix of $X$ so that all rows sum up to $1$.

Is there any way we can find $X$? If yes, how?

Thanks for any thoughts and help :)

Comment: Offhand this sounds like $2n$ equations in $n^2$ variables...

Comment: No. For a permutation matrix all of these sums are equal to $1$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan indeed, but what if we guarantee that both the row sums and column sums for $X$ would vary?

Comment: That doesn't matter. You can replace the $1$s in a permutation matrix with whatever numbers you want, which then become the column sums. After normalizing so that the row sums are all $1$ you get back the original permutation matrix.

Comment: makes sense, thanks!